# Are these two same insects?

Tags: entomology

[image] These guys are infesting my place. I searched through this site and came to know that they are cloth moths. All these days I used to see the left one type in the image. Recently I started to get the ones looking like the right ones.

As you can see the the right ones have a black border like thing at the end of the casing which the other kind does not have. Also , it looks like it has a different kind of structure from the left one, no ? I don't know..
So, are they the same ones or different kinds ?